# incorrect header check while trying to uncompressed s3 object body?

Tags: node.js, lambda, zlib, aws-s3-client

I compress and upload an object to s3 using the follwoing code:

```
 let data: string | Buffer = JSON.stringify(rules);
  let contentType = "application/json";
  let encoding = null;
  let filename = `redirector-rules.json`;
  if (format === "gz") {
    contentType = "application/gzip";
    encoding = "gzip";
    filename = `redirector-rules.gz`;
    const buf = Buffer.from(data, "utf-8");
    data = zlib.gzipSync(buf);
  }

  // res.end(data);
  // return res.status(200).send(data);
  await s3.upload(filename, data, contentType, encoding);
```

I am assuming this is working correctly since when I donwload the result file using `aws s3 cp` command it works just fine and I am able to uncompress it on my machine. additionally, possibly unrelated fact, if I downlaod via the conole for s3, my system is unable to uncompress it and it possibly corrupt or truncated.

on the other end I have a lambda code that read get the object and attempt to decompress it:

```
const getRules = async (rulesCommand: GetObjectCommand): Promise<Config> => {

    const resp = await fetchRulesFile(rulesCommand);
    const data = await parseResponse(resp, rulesCommand);

    return data;

};

const fetchRulesFile = async (rulesCommand: GetObjectCommand): Promise<GetObjectCommandOutput> => {
  try {
    console.log(`Retrieving rules file with name ${rulesCommand.input.Key}`);
    const resp = await client.send(rulesCommand);
    return resp;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`Error retrieving rules file: ${err}`);
  }
};

const parseResponse = async (resp: GetObjectCommandOutput, rulesCommand: GetObjectCommand): Promise<Config> => {
  const { Body } = resp;
  if (!Body) {
    throw new Error("No body in response");
  }

  let data: string = await Body.transformToString();

  if (rulesCommand.input.Key?.endsWith(".gz")) {
    console.log(`Uncompressing rules file with name ${rulesCommand.input.Key}`);
    try {
      data = zlib.gunzipSync(data).toString("utf-8");
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(`Error decompressing rules file: ${err}`);
    }
  }

  return JSON.parse(data) as Config;
};
```

but I keep getting this error:  `Error: incorrect header check`

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by using Readable and streams in the parseResponse function:

```
const parseResponse = async (
  resp: GetObjectCommandOutput,
  rulesCommand: GetObjectCommand
): Promise<Config> => {
  const { Body } = resp;
  if (!Body) {
    throw new Error("No body in response");
  }

  let data = "";
  const readableStream = new Readable();
  readableStream._read = () => {}; // noop
  // @ts-ignore
  Body.on("data", (chunk : any) => {
    readableStream.push(chunk);
    data += chunk;
  });
  // @ts-ignore
  Body.on("end", () => {
    readableStream.push(null);
  });
  const gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
  const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let buffer = "";
    readableStream.pipe(gunzip);
    gunzip.on("data", (chunk) => {
      buffer += chunk;
    });
    gunzip.on("end", () => {
      resolve(buffer);
    });
    gunzip.on("error", reject);
  });
  return result as Config;
};
```

I had to add `@ts-ignore` at `Body.on` because of type mismatch. But it still worked in the compiled JS handler and fixing it with conversion seemed a bit complex.

Comment: thx! this worked for me but I wish there was a better way.

Comment: I think you can remove this part: 
`
const readableStream = new Readable();
  readableStream._read = () => {}; // noop
  // @ts-ignore
  Body.on("data", (chunk : any) => {
    readableStream.push(chunk);
    data += chunk;
  });
  // @ts-ignore
  Body.on("end", () => {
    readableStream.push(null);
  });
`
And replace `readableStream.pipe(gunzip):` with `resp.Body.pipe(gunzip);`